# The deadbolt on the door is broken preventing opening the door.

Tags: deadbolt

Schlage Deadbolt won't unlock to open door so I took off the lock portion to try to open it but the spring broke...nothing moves. It looks like it wasn't installed correctly, because there wasn't a strike plate and I can see that the bolt is stuck/jammed in the door frame.  What's the best way to get the bolt out without damaging the door? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This may  just be friction from the door frame pressing on the bolt, caused by humidity changes or a shift in the frame. If so, pulling or pushing on the door while trying to retract the bolt may loosen things enough to let you retract the bolt.

If not, you can try pulling the hinge pins and removing the door from that side.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I was able to pull the hinge pins, but will need another person to remove door.

Comment: If you can access the inside and remove the lock you should be able to retract the bolt. Many dead bolts don't have a strike plate like a normal door lock. Some have a steel plate behime the jamb. Once the lock mechanism is removed it might take some pressure on the door and a screw driver to pull the bolt back but it may be less damage to the Jamb and door by trying to remove the door with the bolt extended.

Comment: @edbeal: I'm presuming that was already tried and failed for some reason.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. We tried all of the suggestions mentioned but was still unable to retract the bolt. We removed the hinge pins, tapped the outside of the door with a rubber mallet, and carefully used a crowbar to pry the hinges apart from the inside. SUCCESS!!! We were able to remove the door without any damage to the door or door frame and replaced the locks.

Comment: Please upvote any helpful answers, and then either select or provide an answer to accept. This question will remain open until you do.